# Request right after Response?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am a bit lost with the following scenario:

My webservice consumes POST requests with form data. I have to reply with 200 OK or otherwise the senders thinks the request failed.

Immediately after answering with 200 I would like to proceed to call another webservice on a remote host with some of the data I have just received.

My webservice consumes the POST request with the `@GET` annotation. That works I can read all the form data. To call the other webservice I used the Jersey Client API. That works fine too.

I just can't figure out how to switch from switching from one call to another. Everything is programmed with Jersey 2 and deployed in Tomcat, so no real Application Server. There is no full Java EE stack available.

Am I missing some middleware? Do I need to implement a custom event-loop or some message broker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there's any *"standard"* way to handle this, but there's a [`CompletionCallback`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/CompletionCallback.html) we can register with an [`AyncResponse`](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/container/AsyncResponse.html).

> **CompletionCallback:**
>
> A request processing callback that receives request processing completion events.
>
> A completion callback is invoked when the whole request processing is over, i.e. once a response for the request has been processed and sent back to the client or in when an unmapped exception or error is being propagated to the container.

The `AsyncResponse` is meant to handle requests asynchronously , but we can immediately call `resume` to treat it like it was synchronous. A simple example would be something like

```
@Path("/callback")
public class AsyncCallback {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void postWithAsync(@Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse,  
                                         SomeObject object) {

        asyncResponse.register(new CompletionCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Throwable error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    System.out.println("Processing new Request");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Exception in Request handling");
                }
            }
        });
        Response response = Response.ok("Success").build();
        // Carry on like nothing happened
        asyncResponse.resume(response);
    }
}
```

You can see more explanation at [Asynchronous Server-side Callbacks](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e8863)

Comment: Thanks! I was even reading this chapter but totally overlooked this part. Just tried it out. Thats probably all I need.